# return object from overloaded operator>>

Tags: c++

C++ is not my first language choice. And I do not know if I think completely wrong.

What I have created so far.

I have a class with an attribute. A pointer to the class Shape. I've named the class ShapePtr.

ShapePtr.h

```
class ShapePtr{
    public:

        ShapePtr():sPtr(0){};
        ShapePtr(Shape *s):sPtr(s){};
        ShapePtr(const ShapePtr *s){
            if( s->sPtr != 0 )
                sPtr = s->sPtr->clone();
            else
                sPtr = 0;
            };

        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const ShapePt &s);

        Shape *sPtr; //Points on Shape or 0

    };
```

ShapePtr.cpp

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const ShapePtr &s){

        std::size_t found;
        std::string row, theShape;

        while(!is.eof()){

            getline(is,row);
            found = row.find(":");
            theShape= row.substr(0,found);

            if(theShape.compare("CIRKEL") == 0)
            {

                ShapePtr tempSPtr = ShapePtr(new Circle);
    /*return*/  ShapePtr test = ShapePtr(tempSPtr.sPtr -> creat(row));

            }else if(theShape.compare("POLYGON") == 0){
                /*...*/
            }else if(theShape.compare("RECTANGLE") == 0){
                /*...*/
            }else if(theShape.compare("POINT") == 0){
                /*...*/
            }
             /*else if ...*/

        };
```

Class Shape which is a an abstract base class with a virtual function creat().

Shape.h

```
class Shape{
    public:
        virtual Shape* creat(std::string row) = 0;
};
```

Circle which is one of many subclasses with different shapes.

Circle.h

```
class Circle : public Shape{
    public:
        Circle();
        Circle( double x, double y, double r) : Shape(x, y), radie(r){};

        Shape *creat(std::string row);

    private:
        double radie;
};
```

Circle.cpp

```
Circle::Circle()
: Shape(0, 0), radie(0)
{};

Shape * Circle::creat(std::string row){

    std::size_t found1, found2;
    std::string xstr, ystr, rstr;
    double xd, yd, rd;

    found1 = row.find("(");
    found2 = row.find(",");

    //X position
    xstr = row.substr(found1 + 1,found2 - found1 -1);

    found1 = row.find(",");
    found2 = row.find(")");

    //Y position
    ystr = row.substr(found1 +1,found2 -found1 -1);

    found1 = row.find_last_of(":");

    //Radie
    rstr = row.substr(found1 + 1);

    //To double
    xd = atof(xstr.c_str());
    yd = atof(ystr.c_str());
    rd = atof(rstr.c_str());

    return new Circle(xd, yd, rd);
};
```

My problem is that I want to be able to read a file in main with the ShapePtr overrided operator>>. Then I want to retune the object created in the ShapePtr function. In my code above, the object is called test. I have written a comment /*return*/ on the same line to clarify. In main, this object will be added to a list.

I can not change operator>> to return ShapePtr instead of an istream because then it's no longer overrided.

main should look like this

```
int main(){

    ifstream is("fil.dat");
    istream_iterator<ShapePtr> shapein(is), endofshapein;
    list<ShapePtr> shapelist(shapein, endofshapein );
}
```

An example of how fil.dat can look

```
POLYGON: { (0,0) (10,0) (5,2) (5,5) }
CIRKEL: (5,5) Radie:4
RECTANGLE: (4,10) Hight:4 Width:2
POINT: (6,7) :1
```

To clarify my problem. To read and create the shapes is not the problem. They are created and can be printed in ShapePtr. The problem is how to get them to the list in main. Can it be done or have I created a lot of code that is bad from the start?

I have obviously not written all my code here in the forum and I may have written too much anyway. But I rather write too much than too little.

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: `friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const ShapePt &s);` `const` is wrong here. You cannot target a `const` reference as input.

Comment: not to mention that `ShapePt` is different from `ShapePtr`.

Comment: Not to mention that the ShapePtr class it utterly pointless. It doesn't even have a destructor to ensure the pointer gets freed. Why not just use std::unique_ptr?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't idiomatically overriding `std::istream& operator>>`, so `std::istream_iterator` won't do the right thing.

The correct signature is `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, ShapePtr &s)`. Once you have that, you can assign to `s` and `return is;`

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, ShapePtr &s){
    std::string row;

    if(getline(is,row)) {
        std::size_t found = row.find(":");
        std::string theShape = row.substr(0, found);

        if(theShape.compare("CIRKEL") == 0){
            Circle c; 
            s = c.create(row);
            return is;
        } else if(theShape.compare("POLYGON") == 0){
            /*...*/
        } else if(theShape.compare("RECTANGLE") == 0){
            /*...*/
        } else if(theShape.compare("POINT") == 0){
            /*...*/
        } /*else if ...*/
    }
    return is;
}
```

However you have a large number of other problems with your design, like `Circle::create` being a member function returning a `new Circle` rather than being a constructor, leaking `Shapes` because you use raw pointers and don't take care to `delete`s things etc.